# In BF3, can you steal a vehicle that has enemy players in it?

Tags: battlefield-3

A friend told me that he saw a video of someone piloting an enemy transport chopper full of enemies (The enemy pilot had bailed out or something).  He then proceeded to crash the chopper, getting kill points for all the enemies inside (and probably a suicide too).

Is this possible, or was my friend watching an older Battlefield game, or the wrong game entirely?

Comment: Only if they are sniped or killed otherwise before.. Obviously, they can't join the ride with you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Yes you can](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6kjFQlSyTI), although it's almost certainly a bug. (The video was meant to disprove an earlier version of the same bug, where anyone who stole a vehicle with an enemy still in the co-pilot seat would be flagged a member of the other team, and therefore invincible unless friendly fire was on.)

Comment: I could have sworn I've done this a couple of times in a humvee, but not recently.

Answer (score 2):

This just happened to me.

I was the gunner in a tank on Kharg Island, then out of nowhere the driver name became RED and I was in an enemy vehicle. It would not let me stay inside and I was automatically ejected after 5 seconds

Answer (score 1):

No, its not possible.  Unless there is a bug or a glitch i have missed.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. I have done in BF3 in conquest on the Gulf of Oman map on RU team, at US aircraft carrier in their venom. Basically I parachuted to their base then got in the venom and 3 seconds later there was a white name as a gunner.

I check the score board and notice the white named person wasn't on my team and that it was an enemy. After driving the stolen venom back to main land I get destroyed by the viper. I still don't know how it happened and I know it was a glitch and not a bug or mod.